# How to check if multiple files exist in documents directory? (Swift)

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I can check if one file exists with this method:

```
let fileNameOne = "savedpicture1"
let fileURLOne = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(fileNameOne) 

if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURLOne.path) {
       removeImage(itemName: "savedpicture1", fileExtension: "jpg")
 } else {
        print("There was no image to remove")
 }
```

My problem is having to repeat the same lines of code for multiple files. For instance, I would like to check if the files exist in an array of paths, but I would have to repeat the code from above for each file, and it seems too redundant. I'm wondering if there's a way to check multiple files instead of repeating the code for each single path. ".fileExists" only enables me to check one path:

```
 let filePaths = [fileURLOne.path, fileURLTwo.path, fileURLThree.path, 
 fileURLFour.path]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a method for example

```
func checkFiles(with fileNames: [String] {
    for fileName in fileNames {
        let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName) 
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
            removeImage(itemName: fileName, fileExtension: "jpg")
        } else {
            print("There was no image to remove at", fileURL)
        }
    }
}
```

and call it

```
let fileNames = ["savedpicture1", "savedpicture2", "savedpicture3",  "savedpicture4"] 
checkFiles(with: fileNames)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that's exactly what I was looking for.